# multiple concepts for template class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have the class below, but it only works with floating points. How to add integers too? That is multiple requires statements? or is there something that can include all numerical types?

Or there is a better way?

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
requires std::floating_point<T> // How to add integral, signed integral, etc
class Complex {
private:
    T re = 0;
    T im = 0;

public:
    Complex() {
        std::cout << "Complex: Default constructor" << std::endl;
    };

    Complex(T real) : re{re} {
        std::cout << "Complex: Constructing from assignement!" << std::endl;
    };

    bool operator<(const Complex<T>& other) {
        return re < other.re && im < other.im;
    }
};

#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `||` your concepts such as

```
requires std::floating_point<T> || std::integral<T>
```

you can also create a concept this way

```
template <typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;
```

then you can use this concept with your class

```
template <class T>
requires arithmetic<T>
class Complex
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There's already an [`std::is_arithmetic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) type trait that can be used with your requires clause:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
class Complex
{
   ...
```

Note that if you go with a custom `Arithmetic` concept for this (I Imagine the standard library will provide one at some point but say you're impatient) it's clean(er) to write:

```cpp
template <Arithmetic T>
class Complex
{
    ...
```